# How To Use Object Returned By VB.NET Web Service

Tags: ajax, vb.net, web-services

I have a Javascript function that passes a string into a VB.NET Web Method. Here is the Javascript

```
function jQuerySerial() {
//I SET A VARIABLE TO THE STRING I IS PASSED INTO MY WEB METHOD
var str = "{ 'str': 'hello world'}";

//THEN I PASS IT INTO MY VB.NET WEB METHOD
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
url: "test_WebService.asmx/testWebService",
data: str,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (e) {
    alert("It worked: " + e);
},
error: function (e) {
    alert("There was an error retrieving records: " + e);
}
});
}//END jQuerySerial
```

Here is the VB.NET web Method. The Web Method simply takes the string and sends it back to the Javascript:

```
   <WebMethod( )> _
Public Function testWebService(str As String) As String
    Return str
End Function
```

When the Web Method returns successfully my AJAX block returns the following message:

```
"It worked: [object Object]"
```

So my question is, how do I use the returned object? The object should be a string containing the words "hello world" but how do I access the string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net WebMethods wrap their return values in a JSON object with a `d` property.  (You can see this in the response body in the browser's developer tools)

You need to write `e.d` to get the actual value.

Comment: Thanks @Slaks, this solved the problem. I appreciate your taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

if you do:

```
$(e).text()
```

You'll get your text;

So change this to be:

```
function jQuerySerial() {
//I SET A VARIABLE TO THE STRING I IS PASSED INTO MY WEB METHOD
var str = "{ 'str': 'hello world'}";

//THEN I PASS IT INTO MY VB.NET WEB METHOD
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
url: "test_WebService.asmx/testWebService",
data: str,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (e) {
    alert("It worked: " + $(e).text());
},
error: function (e) {
    alert("There was an error retrieving records: " + e);
}
});
}//END jQuerySerial
```